# variable in query for table not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to select data from a table using a variable as the table name. If I type in the exact table name, it works fine. I have tried variable `$currenttable` with `.$currenttable.` and just `$currenttable` but it doesn't work.

```
$paid= 'SELECT * FROM $currenttable WHERE NYID = "'.$search.'" and STATUS = "PAID"';
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $notpaid) or die("Couldn't execute NOT PAID MEM query. ". mysqli_error());
```

Comment: All you need to do is probably to write it like this: `$paid= 'SELECT * FROM ' . $currenttable . ' WHERE NYID = "'.$search.'" and STATUS = "PAID"'; $query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $notpaid) or die("Couldn't execute NOT PAID MEM query. ". mysqli_error());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your select statement in single quotes so the variable name is not being evaluated by PHP. Change it to

```
$paid= 'SELECT * FROM ' . $currenttable . ' WHERE NYID = "'.$search.'" and STATUS = "PAID"';
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it. If it helped please consider marking this answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark.